# add Other Linker Flags -ObjC to face book SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, linker

I added the Box SDK and so had to set `Other Linker Flag` to `-ObjC`, but then I get an error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Volumes/DATA/Projects/Conojo/Conojo 3 3 2 2 2/Conojo/GTL"'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from: objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I include the Box SDK and avoid the error?

Comment: THe error looks wonderful... What should we do with this......

Comment: This is not a question. What do you expect people to respond with when you only post the output from the error console?

Comment: Why are you using -ObjC, what requires it ?

Comment: Add Box SDK and Other Linker Flag  set -ObjC to Error

Comment: (Wain)Add Box SDK to Requer to -ObjC Other crass in application

Comment: At least try to update your question with better information / explanation of the situation and problem (and formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your linker flags to remove -ObjC. Instead, add:

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libBoxSDK.a
```

to load only the Box SDK contents that are required (without affecting Parse SDK).

Comment: thanks .... Issues solve